# django when updating pass the required field

Tags: python, django

I want to update postModel in my template.But in models.py i don't use blank=True and null=True because when model is creating, i want from user can not pass this area without adding image.But when i was doing update, i want from user they can pass this area if they want and showing image link.How can i do this?

models.py

```
class postModel(models.Model):
    
    STATUS = (
        ("yes" , "YES"),
        ("no" , "NO")
    )
    image=models.ImageField(
        upload_to="post_images",
    )
    title=models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
    slug=AutoSlugField(populate_from="title",unique=True)
    content=RichTextField()
    writer=models.ForeignKey(CustomUserModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="articles")
    categories=models.ManyToManyField(CategoryModel,related_name="posts")
    is_slider=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS,default="no",verbose_name="IS slider?")
    created_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    readingCount=models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    is_published=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS,default="no",verbose_name="Is published")
```

forms.py

```
class addPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = postModel
        fields=("title","categories","content","is_slider","image")
        widgets = {
            "title" : TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control","style":"color: black; text-transform: none;"}),
            "categories" : SelectMultiple(attrs={"class":"form-control"}),
            "content" : Textarea(attrs={"class":"form-control"}),
            "is_slider" : Select(attrs={"class":"form-control"}),
            "image" : FileInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}),
          
        }
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="login_view")
def update_post(request,slug):
    post=get_object_or_404(postModel,slug=slug)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = addPostForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            post=form.save(commit=False)
            post.writer=request.user
            post.save()     
            form.save_m2m()      
            return redirect("update_post",slug=post.slug)
        else:
            return redirect("update_post",slug=post.slug)

    form=addPostForm(instance=post)
    context={
        "form":form,
        "post":post,
    }
    return render(request,"update_post.html",context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `FileInput` as the widget you should use [`ClearableFileInput` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#clearablefileinput) this will display the currently set file and also render a checkbox which the user can use to *clear* the file if they want. If they don't select anything here it will be considered they want to keep the current file. Since your file is required this checkbox will not be rendered but its internal logic would still be present and the user can skip uploading the file (the old one would be kept):

```
class addPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = postModel
        fields=("title","categories","content","is_slider","image")
        widgets = {
            "title" : TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control","style":"color: black; text-transform: none;"}),
            "categories" : SelectMultiple(attrs={"class":"form-control"}),
            "content" : Textarea(attrs={"class":"form-control"}),
            "is_slider" : Select(attrs={"class":"form-control"}),
            # use ClearableFileInput ↓
            "image" : forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}),
          
        }
```

Also when updating an instance you need to pass it to the form which you haven't done in case of a POST request:

```
@login_required(login_url="login_view")
def update_post(request,slug):
    post=get_object_or_404(postModel,slug=slug)
    form=addPostForm(instance=post)
    if request.method == "POST":
        # `request.POST or None` is an anti-pattern, plus not even needed here your if condition already checks that
        form = addPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.writer = request.user
            post=form.save()
            return redirect("update_post",slug=post.slug)
        # Don't redirect for invalid forms just render them back
    context={
        "form":form,
        "post":post,
    }
    return render(request,"update_post.html",context)
```

Comment: oh thanks. url does appear but same problem is still available.If ı didn't choose any file image ,ı have an error form is not valid.What can i do

Comment: @MuhammetAydoğan you haven't passed the instance to the form in case of a POST request...

Comment: Thank you very much :) It is working now.